# Pull and Push images in Docker and Azure

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019, azure-container-registry

I am trying to pull and push images between Docker Desktop and Azure and Visual Studio 2019.

currently I can push from VS2019 by Publish option and I can push to Docker and Azure Container Registry.

How do I pull from Azure to Docker? I believe there is an issue with security accounts between the 2 systems. After all, my Docker account is not my Azure account. I came across this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal

which contains a script. Is this the right article to solve my problem? I made a copy of the script but I am struggling to run it. If I save it to `assignpermissions.sh` file and run `wsl ./assignpermissions.sh` it complains that **az** does not exist.

So
Is that the right article to help me (eventually) pull and push between Azure and Docker?
How do I run the script when calling **az** is causing an error?
Any other things I need to watch out for in the next step?

Answer (score 1):

#### [Log in to a registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-powershell#log-in-to-a-registry)

There are several ways to authenticate to your private container registry.

- ##### Azure CLI

The recommended method when working in a command line is with the Azure CLI command [az acr login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr#az_acr_login). For example, to log in to a registry named *myregistry*, log into the Azure CLI and then authenticate to your registry:

```
az login
az acr login --name myregistry
```

- ##### Azure PowerShell

The recommended method when working in PowerShell is with the Azure PowerShell cmdlet [Connect-AzContainerRegistry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerregistry/connect-azcontainerregistry). For example, to log in to a registry named *myregistry*, log into Azure and then authenticate to your registry:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Connect-AzContainerRegistry -Name myregistry
```

You can also log in with [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/). For example, you might have [assigned a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#service-principal) to your registry for an automation scenario. When you run the following command, interactively provide the service principal appID (username) and password when prompted. For best practices to manage login credentials, see the [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) command reference:

```
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io
```

Both commands return `Login Succeeded` once completed.

**Note:** You might want to use Visual Studio Code with Docker extension for a faster and more convenient login.

**Tip:** Always specify the fully qualified registry name (all lowercase) when you use docker login and when you tag images for pushing to your registry. In the examples in this article, the fully qualified name is *myregistry.azurecr.io*.

#### [Push the image to your registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-powershell#push-the-image-to-your-registry)

Now that you've tagged the image with the fully qualified path to your private registry, you can push it to the registry with `docker push`:

```
docker push myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx
```

#### [Pull the image from your registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-powershell#pull-the-image-from-your-registry)

Use the `docker pull` command to pull the image from your registry:

```
docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx
```